# Django 1.11 One-to-Many relationship no related set

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

So I have two models:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    """ Holds basic user data. """
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)  # id is taken from data.


class ConsumptionTimePoint(models.Model):
    """ Individual consumption time points with a One-to-Many relationship with UserData """
    user_data = models.ForeignKey(UserData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And when I try and test them by creating them both, and their relationship in a test:

```
def test_basic_model_creation(self):
    user_data_object = UserData.objects.create(id=1)
    user_data_object.save()
    consumption_time_point_object = ConsumptionTimePoint.objects.create(user_data=user_data_object)                                                                        
    consumption_time_point_object.save()
    self.assertIsNotNone(consumption_time_point_object.user_data)
    self.assertEquals(1, len(user_data_object.consumption_time_point_set.all()))
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'UserData' object has no attribute 'consumption_time_point_set'
```

But from my understanding that's the correct way to get the set. Have I misnamed something? Or is this a testing issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the related queryset the class name is lowercased and `_set` is appended. Try `consumptiontimepoint_set`

You can also set the reverse relation name manually by using the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) parameter.

Comment: Ah damn, new it was a dumb error. Thanks for the assist - I'll accept when it allows.